# Producer/director stages alien abduction to help single mom and kid facing eviction

Tags: story-identification, aliens, space, alien-abduction

I remember this movie from the 80's or early 90's. Might have been a TV movie. Looking for the name. Plot outline:

- movie producer/director is making an alien-themed film
- has a young boy (hispanic/latino, perhaps) as a helper around the office and/or set
- boy and his mother are about to be evicted by a wealthy landlord that lives in a big house sort-of in the country (i.e. not suburbs)
- producer/director uses props and special effects to "land" a UFO on the landlord's property during dinner
- "abduct" the guy, load the UFO onto a semi trailer, drive back to soundstage
- the semi with the ufo on the trailer gets pulled over by a cop at one point and it looks like the jig is up (false alarm)
- take the guy aboard the "mothership" where he sees a particular symbol all over
- they tell him he'll recognize the "chosen one" or whatever by that symbol
- at some point in this you see an actor in an alien suit off-duty smoking a cigarette
- return the landlord home or release him
- they rush to get a medallion to the boy with that logo on it
- landlord sees it, takes the heat off the mother/boy re: eviction
- happily ever after?